# How can I rightpad continus numbers to one cloumn in big query table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my problem:
I have one column in the table, type of Integer.

The length of any entity in the column is 7 and thus fixed.

I want to right pad 0000 to 9999 to every entity in this column, so one entity in the original table will correspond to 10k new columns in a new table.

For example:

The first entry of the original table is '1234567',
I want to generate:
12345670000
12345670001
12345670002
12345670003
...
12345679999

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT value * 10000 + step AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 9999)) step
```

You can test, play with above using that simplified example from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1234567 value 
)
SELECT value * 10000 + step AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 9999)) step
-- ORDER BY value
```